# when device is arabic language then input field is showing arabic for type="number"

Tags: html, css, mobile, dojo, translation

we are developing hybrid mobile application using DOJO 1.10.3

I have a input fields with type number that fields are prepulated and i applied english times new roman font to the input field. When the device language is set to Arabic, prepopulated input field is showing Arabic numbers but i want to show english numbers only.

that prepopulated inputfields i am trying to editing in that time it is showing english numbers.

don't want it to translate it to Arabic Numerals. How can I make this?

[problem screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hw2M.png)

```js
var jsonFiled={'firstField':"1kjj678",'secondField':58815}
 document.getElementById('1stField').value=jsonFiled.firstField;
 document.getElementById('2ndField').value=jsonFiled.secondField;
```

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: Times New Roman;
 src: url(font-face/Times_New_Roman_Normal.ttf);
}

.ui-page {
 font-family: Times New Roman !important;
  } 

.ui-header{
 height: 42px!important;
 border-top: 2px solid rgba(106, 106, 106, 1.0);
 border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(106, 106, 106, 1.0);
 display: table;
 vertical-align: top !important;
 top: 0px !important;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0px !important; 
 right:0px; 
 left:0px;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 1000; 
 position: fixed !important; 
 background: rgba(160, 32, 64, 1.0);
 font-family: Times New Roman !important; 
}
  
.ui-content {
 border: none !important;
 margin: 0px !important;
 position: absolute !important;
 bottom:0px !important;
 left: 0px !important;
 right:0px !important ;
 top:20px !important;
 padding:0px 15px 0px 15px !important;  
 font-family: Times New Roman !important;
 }   

.ui-footer{
 background: rgba(160, 32, 64, 1.0);
 height: 44px;
 border-top: 2px solid rgba(106, 106, 106, 1.0);
 border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(106, 106, 106, 1.0);
 vertical-align: bottom !important;
 bottom: 0px !important;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 font-family: Times New Roman !important;
}

input {
 margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-indent: 10px;
 color: rgba(23, 82, 117, 1.0);
 display: block;
 width: 85%;
 height: 34px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 1.0);
 border-radius: 0px;
 background-color: white !important;
 outline: none !important;
 font-family: Times New Roman !important;
}  

button {
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 18px auto 0px auto;
 display: block;
 width: 85.5%;
 border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
 height: 35px;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 2.4;
 border-radius: 7px;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(160, 32, 64, 1.0);
 background: #fceabb;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fceabb 0%, #fccd4d 50%, #f8b500 51%, #fbdf93
  100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fceabb 0%, #fccd4d 50%, #f8b500 51%,
  #fbdf93 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fceabb 0%, #fccd4d 50%, #f8b500 51%, #fbdf93
  100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fceabb',
  endColorstr='#fbdf93', GradientType=0); /* IE6-9 */
 font-family: Times New Roman !important;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
      
      <title>errwer</title>
<meta name="viewport"
 content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no,target-densityDpi=device-dp">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<!--
       <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
       <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
      -->
      
   
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
      <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body style="display: none;" lang="en">

<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="view1"
  data-dojo-props="selected:false" class="ui-page">
 <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view0" data-dojo-props="selected:true">

  <div class="ui-header" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
    data-dojo-props="label:'Header',fixed: 'top'"  data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-hide-during-focus="false">
  </div>
   <div class="ui-content" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Container">
       
      
       <input data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" id="1stField" style="font-family:Times New Roman!important;">
    
    <input data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" id="2ndField" type="number" style="font-family:Times New Roman!important;">
      

       <button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button">SUBMIT</button>
     </div>  
       
   <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" class="ui-footer"
     data-dojo-props="label:'Footer',fixed: 'bottom'"></div>
     
  </div>
    </div> 
      
      
      
      <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
      <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try adding `pattern="[0-9]{10}"` to the input, change the 10 if you want more digits

Comment: i try that also but not working

Comment: what about putting  `accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"` on the form tag?

Comment: it is also not working, i modified the question please find it

Answer (score -1):

Is this work? set attribute `lang` at `body` element

```
<body lang="en">
```